# abap count similar row values

Tags: abap

```
 IF ls_th_sum_lab_ndt IS not INITIAL.
        ls_th_sum_lab_ndt-ndt_flag = 'X'.
        ls_th_sum_lab_ndt-zwc_cat = 'NDT'.
if there are more than 2 zwc_cat that equal to NDT change the other one to MH

        APPEND ls_th_sum_lab_ndt TO gt_th_sum_lab_ndt.
      ENDIF.
```

Basically what I want to do:

Update  `ls_th_sum_lab_ndt-zwc_cat=MH` if  `ls_th_sum_lab_ndt-zwc_cat="NDT" >2` set second row to MH

Thank You in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
DATA: lv_count type i,
      lv_index type sy-tabix.
...
LOOP AT gt_th_sum_lab_ndt INTO ls_th_sum_lab_ndt WHERE zwc_cat = 'NDT'.
  lv_count = lv_count + 1.
  if lv_count >= 2.
    lv_index = sy-tabix.
    exit.
  endif.
ENDLOOP.

CHECK lv_count >= 2.
READ TABLE gt_th_sum_lab_ndt INTO ls_th_sum_lab_ndt INDEX lv_index.
ls_th_sum_lab_ndt-zwc_cat = 'MH'.
MODIFY gt_th_sum_lab_ndt FROM ls_th_sum_lab_ndt INDEX lv_index.
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: there are two records with the same threshold name the first's field must be MH the seconds must be NDT....the problem is that the program is 10.000 rows long I am having a hard time to find the place where I should change this

Comment: If there are only 2 then if you evaluate `lv_count > 2` then the program will wait until `lv_count` is at least 3. It is better to use `lv_count >= 2` in your requeriment. On the other hand, I suggest you to do the replacement after you create the table with the data.

Comment: is there any way to do this without any loop,couse some values in the table get doubled